# Acceder a datos privados de un objeto

Tags: c++

Hemos empezado a trabajar en un proyecto que usa una librería que [no tenemos permitido modificar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_heredado). Nos encontramos con el problema de que necesitamos cambiar el estado interno de algunos objetos de esta librería pero la interfaz de dichos objetos no ofrece métodos para ello:

```
class Clase
{
    std::string dato1;
    std::string dato2;
public:
    void actualiza1(std::string valor) { dato1 = valor; }
};
```

Como puede verse en el ejemplo simplificado, podemos cambiar `Clase::dato1` pero no tenemos manera de modifciar `Clase::dato2`:

```
Clase c;
c.actualiza1("Dato 1"); // Correcto.
c.dato2 = "Dato 2";     // Error! dato2 es privado!
```

Hemos intentado cambiar los datos mediante puntero, pero tampoco ha sido posible:

```
Clase c;

using str_pClase = std::string Clase::*;
str_pClase p2 = &Clase::dato2; // Error! dato2 es privado;

c.*p2 = "Dato 2";
```

Como último recurso hemos copiado el redactado los objetos de la librería pero con los miembros públicos, cuando necesitamos cambiar el estado interno del objeto usamos el `new` de emplazamiento:

```
class Clase
{
    std::string dato1;
    std::string dato2;
public:
    void actualiza1(std::string valor) { dato1 = valor; }
};

struct Estructura
{
    std::string dato1;
    std::string dato2;
};

Clase c;
c.actualiza1("Dato 1"); // Correcto.

Estructura *e = new(&c) Estructura;
e->dato2 = "Dato 2";    // Correcto! c.dato2 ahora es 200;
```

Aunque esto parece funcionar, provoca otros errores ya que al construir un objeto sobre otro existente, se llaman los constructores de los sub-objetos y cambian (inicializan) valores del objeto original que no queríamos que fuesen modificados.

¿Es posible saltarse de alguna manera la restricción de acceso a los datos?

---

<sup>Basado en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56232948/forcefully-access-private-member) de SOen</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ¿Es posible saltarse de alguna manera la restricción de acceso a los datos?

No. Lo que intentas hacer es peligroso y va en contra de las normas de C++.

---

Bueno, C++ ignora las restricciones de acceso en un contexto específico: La instanciación explícita de una plantilla. Esto significa que instanciando explícitamente una plantilla podemos acceder a datos privados y protegidos de objetos; lo más práctico sería capturar un puntero a los datos internos. Pero no es fácil.

Si tenemos un objeto que anida un puntero a miembro:

```
template <typename clase_t, typename miembro_t>
struct puntero_a_miembro
{
    using tipo = miembro_t clase_t::*;
};
```

Podemos usarlo como llave de una "[*puerta trasera*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerta_trasera)" a un objeto:

```
template <int id, typename llave_t>
struct puerta_trasera
{
    using tipo_t = typename llave_t::tipo;
    inline static tipo_t llave;
};
```

Para abrir esta puerta trasera con nuestra llave, necesitamos una plantilla a la que podamos hacer una instanciación explícita con parámetros explícitos:

```
template <int id, typename llave_t, typename llave_t::tipo llave>
class abrir : puerta_trasera<id, llave_t>
{
    static inline const int ID = (abrir::puerta_trasera::llave = llave, id);
};
```

La *brujería* anterior es necesaria para inicializar la llave de la puerta trasera una vez (`static`) por cada instancia de la plantilla, así que con tu objeto `Clase`, necesitaremos abrir dos puertas traseras:

```
class Clase
{
    std::string dato1;
    std::string dato2;
public:
    void actualiza1(std::string valor) { dato1 = valor; }
};

// Instancia explícita de la plantilla 'abrir'
// usando la llave 'std::string' de 'Clase' sobre 'Clase::dato1'.
template class abrir<0, puntero_a_miembro<Clase, std::string>, &Clase::dato1>;
//                       Esto es privado, pero no da error --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Instancia explícita de la plantilla 'abrir'
// usando la llave 'std::string' de 'Clase' sobre 'Clase::dato2'.
template class abrir<1, puntero_a_miembro<Clase, std::string>, &Clase::dato2>;
//                       Esto es privado, pero no da error --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

En el contexto de la instanciación explícita de plantilla, no se comprueban los permisos de acceso, por lo tanto podremos acceder a `Clase::dato1` y `Clase::dato2` así:

```
int main()
{
    Clase a, b;

    // Acceso al miembro Clase::dato1 de la instancia 'a'
    a.*puerta_trasera<0, puntero_a_miembro<std::string, Clase>>::llave = "Dato 1";
    // Acceso al miembro Clase::dato2 de la instancia 'a'
    a.*puerta_trasera<1, puntero_a_miembro<std::string, Clase>>::llave = "Dato 2";
    // Acceso al miembro Clase::dato1 de la instancia 'b'
    b.*puerta_trasera<0, puntero_a_miembro<std::string, Clase>>::llave = "Dato 1";
    // Acceso al miembro Clase::dato2 de la instancia 'b'
    b.*puerta_trasera<1, puntero_a_miembro<std::string, Clase>>::llave = "Dato 2";

    return 0;
}
```

La sintáxis es bastante engorrosa, así que lo adecuado sería usar una función plantilla de ayuda:

```
template <int id, typename retorno_t, typename clase_t>
retorno_t &accede(clase_t &clase)
{
    return clase.*puerta_trasera<id, puntero_a_miembro<clase_t, retorno_t>>::llave;
}
```

Por si se quiere llamar a métodos privados, podemos declarar también una función plantilla de ayuda:

```
template <int id, typename retorno_t, typename clase_t, typename ... parametros_t>
retorno_t llama(clase_t &clase, parametros_t ... parametros)
{
    return (clase.*puerta_trasera<id, puntero_a_miembro<clase_t, retorno_t(parametros_t ...)>>::llave)(parametros ...);
}
```

Con estas funciones de ayuda, el acceso a datos privados por la puerta trasera quedaría así:

```
class Clase
{
    std::string dato1;
    std::string dato2;
    void funcion_privada1();
    int funcion_privada2(int, int);
};

template class abrir<0, puntero_a_miembro<Clase, std::string>, &Clase::dato1>;
template class abrir<1, puntero_a_miembro<Clase, std::string>, &Clase::dato2>;
template class abrir<0, puntero_a_miembro<Clase, void()>, &Clase::funcion_privada1>;
template class abrir<0, puntero_a_miembro<Clase, int(int, int)>, &Clase::funcion_privada2>;

int main()
{
    Clase a, b;

    accede<0, int>(a) = "Dato 1";
    accede<0, int>(b) = "Dato 1";
    accede<1, int>(a) = "Dato 2";
    accede<1, int>(b) = "Dato 2";

    llama<0, void>(a);
    llama<0, int>(b, 1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MhmFXw5hZMzYr3oV).