# ¿Cómo acceder a los elementos de un vector de clase? c++

Tags: c++, clase, vectores, iteradores, contenedores

[image: Debo acceder a los elementos con nombre allrouters pero no se como]

[image: En la segunda imagen esta el elemnto lista al que quiero acceder, pero no se como indicar que de esta lista quiero ver los elementos de allrouters]

Debo acceder a los elementos con nombre `allrouters` pero no se como.

En la segunda imagen esta el elemento lista al que quiero acceder (donde está `allrouters`), pero no se como indicar que de esa lista quiero manipular los elementos de `allrouters`, ya que hay otros vectores en mi clase, o sea en "lista" hay más vectores pero solo quiero acceder a uno.

A continuación el código de las dos clases por si es útil:

```
class enrutador{

    public:
        void mejorRuta(int V,int E, int nodo_inicio,char L);
        void visualizar_router();
        void guardarRouter(int V,int E);
        void eliminarRouter(int borrar);
    private:
        map<char,int> router;
        map<char,int> ::iterator I1;

        vector<vector<int>> allrouters;//A este quiero acceder
        vector<vector<int>> itera;

        typedef pair<int, int> ii;//<vecino, costo>
        typedef vector<ii> vii;//todos los vecinos asociados--vector de pares
        vector<vii> adjLis;//vector de vector de pares
        vector<vii> ::iterator I3;
};
```

Otra clase

```
    class red{
    public:
        void agregar_enrutador(int V,int E, int nodo_inicio);
        void visualizar_enrutadores();
        void enrutador_archivo(int nodo_inicio);
        void lista_enrutador(int V,int E, int nodo_inicio);
        void eliminar(int borrar);
    private:
        map<char,enrutador> c2;//deberia ser char por el nodo de inicio
        map<char,enrutador> ::iterator I2;


        vector<enrutador> lista; //a este le ingreso el vector de vectores allrouters
        vector<enrutador> ::iterator Ilist;
        int numnodo=1;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes acceder a miembros privados<sup>1</sup> y el miembro al que quieres acceder es privado:

```
class enrutador{

    ...

    private:
        ...

        vector<vector<int>> allrouters;//A este quiero acceder

        ...
};
```

Tu única solución es dotar la clase de [*getters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method):

```
class enrutador{

    // Acceso de sólo lectura
    const vector<vector<int>> &leer_routers() const { return allrouters; }
    // Acceso lectura/escritura
    vector<vector<int>> &obtener_routers() { return allrouters; }

    private:
        ...

        vector<vector<int>> allrouters;//A este quiero acceder

        ...
};
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup> [Salvo que uses código muy oscuro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/266484/2742).